# setting two objects with same location with python API but turns out their locations are different

Tags: python

I have two objects - car and parking line, I want to set the car and parking line with the same location through python API.

i tried two ways

```
def setObjectLocation(obj, location):
    vec = mathutils.Vector((location[0], location[1], 0))
    inv = obj.matrix_world.copy()
    inv.invert()
    vec_rot = vec * inv
    obj.location =vec_rot 

def setObjectLocation(obj, location):
    vec = mathutils.Vector((location[0], location[1], 0))
    obj.location =vec 

setObjectLocation(car_obj, [3,3])
setObjectLocation(parking_obj,[3,3])
```

both doesn't work, in the first method, the parking line disappeared while in the second method, there are still some distance with the car object and parking object.

is it because the two objects 's original properties are different?

[image]

Comment: Really is a ... image.  Put both objects at origin (0, 0, 0) are the meshes in the position you want. (The object origin is the orange dot)  If not you need to transform the origin.  A screenshot from blender will show if this is the case.

Comment: by "position you want" i mean, is the car in the carpark?

Comment: yes, as you said, i want to set the car and parking spot at the same coordinate, meaning the two objects are overlapped or the car in the car park

Comment: need to transform the orgin, do you think the reason is because the orgin of one object very different from another object?

Comment: well are they..?

Comment: I finally checked the two object, one object is not at the orgin(0,0,0), so that is why they don't fit when loading the model on the same postion

Comment: I find the code to set the position of two objects are fine, the problem is due to the reason that the origin of one object is not (0,0,0). this work could help solve the problem.  http://this%20https//blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/change-pivot-or-local-origin-of-an-object

Comment: @batFINGER would you like to give a answer, so I would accept it